# Number issue with single and double digit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with some numbers. Currently, I have an input box that displays the result of an equation. If the numbers are between "-25" and "-55", they display green. If the numbers are from "-55" to "-65", they are orange. Anything else outside of those ranges are red. The problem that I am having is that numbers "-3", "-4" and "-5" are all outside of that range, but they display as green. "-6" displays as orange. Those numbers should be red. Am I missing something from my code that would fix that?

Thank you!

```
var tb = (num1 * num2) + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num7 + num8 + num9 + num10 + num11 + num13 + num12 + num14;

    if (tb > 0) {
        document.calcForm.resist.value = "+" + Math.floor(tb* 100)/100 + " dBm";
    }
    else
    {
        document.calcForm.resist.value = Math.floor(tb* 100)/100 + " dBm";
    }

       document.calcForm.resist.style.color = "green";

   if (document.calcForm.resist.value < "-26" || document.calcForm.resist.value > "-65") {
        document.calcForm.resist.style.color = "red";
   }
   else { if (document.calcForm.resist.value > "-55") {
        document.calcForm.resist.style.color = "orange";
   }}
```

num1 - num14 are different fields for the equation.

Comment: Because `"-26 dBm" !== -26` Also, `"-26" !== -26`

Comment: you're comparing them as strings. Try `parseFloat(document.calcForm.resist.value) < -26`

Comment: bad coding use some varaibles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were comparing strings to strings, which compares alphabetically, not by value. So, you need to convert `document.calcForm.resist.value` to a number – `parseInt(resist.value)` (see code):

```
var tb = (num1 * num2) + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num7 + num8 + num9 + num10 + num11 + num13 + num12 + num14;
var resist = document.calcForm.resist;
if (tb > 0) {
    resist.value = "+" + Math.floor(tb* 100)/100 + " dBm";
}
else
{
    resist.value = Math.floor(tb* 100)/100 + " dBm";
}
resist.style.color = "green";
if (parseInt(resist.value) < -26 || 
    parseInt(resist.value) > -65) {
    resist.style.color = "red";
}
else if (parseInt(resist.value) > -55) {
    resist.style.color = "orange";
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare values with string type variables. You should not be using quotes for numeric data type.While using numeric comparisons you should use parseInt:

```
if (parseInt(document.calcForm.resist.value) < -26 || parseInt(document.calcForm.resist.value) > -65) {
        document.calcForm.resist.style.color = "red";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens due to the fact that document.calcForm.resist.value is being
treated as string/text because you add "+" and + " dBm" to it

```
document.calcForm.resist.value = "+" + Math.floor(tb* 100)/100 + " dBm";
```

That's why "-3" > "-26", and "-3" < "-65".

Likewise for the rest.

Think of string comparison as: "-1" > "-10" > "-11"

whereas numerical: -1 < -10 < -11

In addition, you should remove the quotes from the numbers at:

```
if (document.calcForm.resist.value < "-26" || document.calcForm.resist.value > "-65")
```

to avoid invoking a string a comparison instead.